# Android Wear: How to go back to home screen after Noitifcation Action press (without canceling notification)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, action

My Intent for the Action press gets a Service, from which I am calling when I'm done with the Service:

```
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
```

Yet the screen remains on my Action Button.